# Distribution of the inbetween prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\ \mathbb J_n\,:=\,\{1\ \ldots\ n\}\ $ be the initial interval of natural numbers, and
$$2=p_0<p_1<\ldots$$
be the increasing sequence of all primes. Let

$$ \forall_{n=1\ 2\ \ldots}\ \ d_n\, :=\, \frac{p_n-p_{n-1}}{p_{n+1}-p_{n-1}} $$

so that $\ p_n = (1-d_n)\cdot p_{n-1} + d_n\cdot p_{n+1}.\ $Consider arbitrary reals:
$$0<a<b<1$$

**QUESTION**

Can you prove or disprove or provide a correct limit or that there is none or a reference for equality:

$$ \lim_{n=\infty}\ \frac 1n\cdot \left |\{k\in\mathbb J_n: a\le d_k\le b\}\right|\ =\ b-a $$

---

> One may also consider the related questions about the frequency of the inequalities $\ p_n^2 > p_{n-1}\cdot p_{n+1}\ $ or $\ p_{n+1}\cdot p_{n+2} > p_n\cdot p_{n+3},\ $ or even some more precise questions too. (There is a slight bias toward the $\ >\ $ inequality because it holds when the intermediate primes or their arithmetic mean are close to the arithmetic mean of the external pair of primes; but this wouldn't matter in the limit, or would it?)

Comment: In your last limit line, shouldn't it be $a\le d_k \le b$, or have I misunderstood your claim?

Comment: I dont understand. Do you mean $d_n$ or $d_k$?

Comment: I am so sorry--I fixed the typo, yes, there should be $d_k$, not $d_n$ at its last apperance of $d_?$.

Comment: Let me mention that the Gauss density of primes $\frac 1{\ln(x)}$ is virtually constant in the multiplicatively short intervals lkie in $\ [p_{n-1};p_{n+1}].\ $ This supports my natural conjecture.

Comment: Perhaps you can get insights from the symetric density conjecture I consider in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132973/would-the-following-conjectures-imply-lim-inf-n-to-inftyp-nk-p-n-ok-lo

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, thank  you. I have already read your Question right away, and will come back too it again.

Comment: I am struck by the thought that this is equivalent to the prime k-tuples conjecture.  It probably isn't, but I could imagine some strong links between the two.  Gerhard "Walk  The Imaginary Bridge First" Paseman, 2016.01.25

Comment: @GerhardPaseman -- I'd like to hear more about your association.