# Is the conjunction of Goldbach and NFPR conjecture actually equivalent to Hardy-Littlewood k-tuple conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems, prime-constellations

In [this previous question of mine](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132973/would-the-following-conjectures-imply-lim-inf-n-to-inftyp-nk-p-n-ok-lo)
I introduce under Goldbach's conjecture the notation  $ r_{0}(n) : =\inf\{r\geq 0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\} $ as well as the related so-called NFPR conjecture which states that  $ \forall\varepsilon>0,\forall x>2,\max \{r_{0}(n),n\leq x\}\ll_{\varepsilon}x^{\varepsilon}$, from which I derive an asymptotics for  $ \lim\inf_{n\to\infty} p_{n+k}-p_{n} $ that is a consequence of Hardy-Littlewood k-tuple conjecture.

I would like to know whether the conjunction of Goldbach and NFPR conjectures is actually equivalent to Hardy-Littlewood's  or if a more precise,  $ \varepsilon $ free upper bound for  $ r_{0}(n) $ is needed : for example do we need a small enough  $ \alpha $ such that  $ r_{0}(n)<C\log^{\alpha}n $ for all sufficiently large  $ n $ and some absolute positive constant  $ C $ and if so would  $ \alpha=2 $ do the job ?