# Can this number be interpreted as a fractal dimension?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, fractals, goldbach-type-problems

Under Goldbach's conjecture, let's denote for a large enough integer $n$ by $r_{0}(n)$ the quantity $\inf\{r>0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^2\}$ and by $k_{0}(n):=\pi(n+r_{0}(n))-\pi(n+r_{0}(n))$.

Let's now consider the density of primes around $n$ at two different scales: first at large scale, hence a global density, $\delta_{0}(n):=\frac{\pi(2n)}{2n}$ and then at small scale, hence a local density, $\delta_{1}(n):=\frac{k_{0}(n)}{2r_{0}(n)}$.

My idea is that, writing $\delta_{1}(n):=\delta_{0}(n)^{\mathcal{D}_{n}}$, the number $\mathcal{D}_{n}$ can be interpreted as the fractal dimension of a "fractal prime curve" in the plane, and thus should be a real number less than $2$. This would imply that $\frac{2r_{0}(n)}{k_{0}(n)}\ll\log^{2} n$ and possibly that $r_{0}(n)\ll\log^{C}n$ for some positive constant $C$.

So, can this interpretation of $\mathcal{D}_{n}$ as a fractal dimension be made rigorous and thus be proven to be less than $2$?