# Tiling the set of integers with intervals of the form $[n-r_{0}(n),n+r_{0}(n)]$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

Assuming Goldbach's conjecture, write $r_{0}(n):=\inf\{r>0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}$ as well as $p_{\pm}(n):=n\pm r_{0}(n)$.

Consider a sequence $(c_{m})_{m>0}$ defined by $c_{1}:=4$ and $c_{m+1}:=\sup\{n\mid n\not\in\mathbb{P}\wedge p_{-}(n)=p_{+}(c_{m})\}$. As conjecturally $r_{0}(n)=O(\log^{C}n)$ (call it conjecture A) for some positive constant $C$, the sequence $(c_{m})_{m>0}$ should be uniquely defined. The first terms are $c_{1}=4$, $c_{2}=8$, $c_{3}=14$...

Note that the derived sequence of general term $c'_{m}:=c_{m+1}-c_{m}$ fulfills $c'_{m}>\max(r_{0}(c_{m}),r_{0}(c_{m+1}))$, so that the quantity $C':=\lim\sup_{m\to\infty}\frac{\log c'_{m}}{\log\log c_{m}}$ provides an upper bound for $C_{0}:=\inf\{C\mid r_{0}(n)=O(\log^{C}n)\}$.

Actually, one even has $c_{m}\leq 2\max(r_{0}(c_{m}),r_{0}(c_{m+1}))$, so $C_{0}=C'$.

I have two questions:

1. can one give an upper bound for $C'$?
2. calling an interval $[p_{-}(c_{m}),p_{+}(c_{m})]$ a "primal tile", does a given tile appear infinitely often so that the sequence $(c_{m})_{m>0}$ defines a tiling of the set of the integers?

Edit: one can also wonder if $\sum_{m>0}c_{m}^{-1}$ converges. If it does, denoting by $L$ the value of the limit of this sum, it could help figure out the speed of growth of the sequence I'm interested in as well as the value of $C'$.

This is inspired by the sequence of the half sums of twin primes $(T_{m})_{m>0}$ whose first terms are $4$, $6$, $12$, $18$, $30$, $42$...whose sum of the reciprocals converges, and fulfill $T_{n}\approx\sum_{0<m\leq n}\log^{2}T_{m}$. Indeed conjecturally there are approximately $\frac{x}{\log^{2}x}$ half sums of twin primes up to $x$, and the derivative of this function is close to $\frac{1}{\log^{2}x}$. Using $f(a+h)=f(a)+hf'(a)+h\varphi(h)$ with $\lim_{h\to 0}\varphi(h)=0$, one gets $f(x+\log^{2}x)\approx f(x)+\log^{2}x\times\frac{1}{\log^{2}x}=f(x)+1$.

The first values of $c_{m}$ being $4$, $8$, $14$, $20$, $32$, $44$ that is $T_{m}+2$ for $1<m\leq 6$, this suggests $C_{0}=C'=2$.

Edit September 2nd, 2021: The fact that the sequence $(c_{k})_{k>0}$ mimicks the sequence of "twin generators" (that is, half sums of twin primes) may come from the fact that denoting by $k_{0}(n)$ the quantity $\pi(n+r_{0}(n))-\pi(n-r_{0}(n))$, $k_{0}(n)$ is maximal given the value of $r_{0}(n)$. Call such an integer $n$ for which $k_{0}(n)$ is maximal given $r_{0}(n)$ (or equivalently, $r_{0}(n)$ minimal for a given value  of $k_{0}(n)$) a $k$-primodense integer, where if $n$ is $k$-primodense, then $k=k_{0}(n)$, and call an integer $n$ primodense if it's $k$-primodense for some $k$. For example a twin generator is $1$-primodense, while $14$ is $2$-primodense.

It follows from [Would the following conjectures imply $\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}p_{n+k}-p_{n}=O(k\log k)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132973/would-the-following-conjectures-imply-lim-inf-n-to-inftyp-nk-p-n-ok-lo) that a $k$-primodense integer $n$ fulfills $2r_{0}(n)=k(1+H_{k})+E_{k}(n)$ where $E_{k}(n)$ is an error term depending on $k$.

As for any $n$, one has $k_{0}(n)<2r_{0}(n)$, maybe one could figure out the value of $K_{0}:=\inf\{K\mid k_{0}(n)\ll\log^{K}n\}$ assuming conjecture A. I thus formulate the conjecture $B$:

Conjecture B
Assume conjecture $A$. Then $K_{0}=C_{0}-1$.

A (conditional) proof thereof would be very welcome.